# I need to convert the file path in windows say from c:\abc\efg\mmm.txt to c:\\abc\\mm.txt?

Tags: c, addslashes, filepath

how do i change a file path which is in the form of `

> c:\abc\efg\mmm.txt

to

> c:\\abc\\mm.txt ?

and what can i do to change the

> **.txt** 
>   extension to, let's say **.doc**?

` 
EDIT:

These paths are just for illustration.

The actual paths are composed of drive letters and any number of subdirectories. And the file extensions can be of any format.

Comment: Is there a rule to convert input to output? Like the output will be one level below "c:\\" and the name will have at most 2 repeating chars?

Comment: there is no rule like that. I just had a file path list which is in the first format but vc2010 couldn't understand and open the path. So i have to make conversions into the second format. That is all

Comment: Are the paths composed of a drive letter, two directories, a 3-letter file name and always a .txt filename? The filename letter to remove is the 1st or the last (or the middle one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is not quite clear. If you ONLY want to duplicate the backslashes AND it is pure C AND you don't have wide chars (i.e. ASCII only), then you can do something along the lines of:

```
char* p = str;
char target[MAX_PATH + 1]; // or some other way to be sure it will hold the transformed string
char* t = target;

while (*p) {
  char ch = *p++;
  if (ch == '\\')
    *t++ = '\\';
  *t++ = ch;
}

*t = '\0';
```

This will duplicate the backslashes. In order to replace the extension, to keep things simple, you may want to detect the extension using `int len = strlen(str);` (may be as simple as checking last characters in the `str`). Once done, you can replace the `while` condition by `while(p - str < len - 3)` and then `strcat(target, "doc");`